# How to filter or cleanup my S3 buckets clutters by log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I use S3 and amazon cloud front to put images.

When I go on amazon S3 interface, it's hard to find the folder where i have put my images because i need to scroll 10 minutes past all the buckets it creates every 15 minutes/hour.  There are literally thousands.

- Is it normal?
- Did I put something wrong on the settings of S3 or of the cloud front file I connected to this S3 folder?
- What should I do to delete them? It seems I can only delete them one by one.

See here a snapshot:
[image]

AND SO ON.....FOR THOUSANDS OF FILES UNTIL...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not buckets, but are actually log files generated by S3 because you enabled logging for your bucket and configured it to save the logs in the same bucket.

If you want to keep logging enabled but make it easier to work with the logs, just use a prefix in the logging configuration or set up logging to use a different bucket.

If you don't need the logs, just disable logging.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot ! indeed i removed it . in which case logging is important? would you advice me keeping logs ?

Comment: You're welcome. It depends on how you want to use S3. You need those access logs if you want to see who accessed your S3 files.

Comment: It can add a "folder" prefix to the place you want to keep your logs (you should, this is valuable information). In the S3 console put "bucket_name/s3_access_logs" as the location of the logs.